# Swift 3 - Cannot Create Bar Button Item

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3

I am new to swift and am trying to have a bunch of view controllers nested in a tab controller nested in a navigation controller.

I'm able to get the names of the tabs to change by setting

```
self.parent?.title = "My Results"
```

However no matter what I try I cannot get a Bar Button Item to show up. I tried the following but nothing has worked so far:

1)Dragging a Bar Button Item to the view (it shows up in XCode but not on the app)

2)Adding it through code like this:

```
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(MyResultsController.myRightSideBarButtonItemTapped(_:)))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

Below is the flow of my application.
[Application flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lanX9.png)

I am needing my application to verify that a user has logged in before showing the navigation (first 2 screens)

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: The viewController you add onto MUST be a navigationController. Otherwise your setting some properties that will be just ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed your view controller in a navigation controller by clicking on it in the storyboard and selecting Editor> Embed in>Navigation Controller from the main menu:

[image]

This will place a navigation bar at the top of the screen, which will display your title.

Comment: That mostly worked. I removed the first navigation controller (before the tab controller) and it shows up. However I was hoping that I could keep the same navigation across all the pages. My app isn't very big so I could copy the same button but its not ideal. Is it possible to do that?